# pyinstaller with tensorflow 1.15 compatability issue? Getting ValueError in compiled app

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile my code that used tensorflow. I've been working with Tensorflow 1.15 although it is compatible with (1.14 and 1.13). Previously had never had issues with pyinstaller but after creating a new conda environment I stopped being able to compile the same code.

To me, it seems like tensorflow and pyinstaller don't play with each other well. I tried a few version combinations and still no luck. I get this error during `import tensorlfow` statement after compilation. The program runs fine in python 3.7 or python 3.6.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_dir\mv_app.py", line 39, in <module>
    from shot_change_detection import shot_change_detection
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "shot_change_detection\shot_change_detection.py", line 42, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1019, in _handle_fromlist
  File "tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
  File "tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: Try installing `tensorflow` with `pip` and If already using pip. Create a `venv` instead of `conda env`.

Comment: After creating and activating a new conda environment, use this code `conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller` to install pyinstaller and `pip install tensorflow` to install tensorflow in new environment and try running your code. Let us know if still issue persists. You can refer [this](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyinstaller)  for more details.